# How to find a specific point in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an binary image data, which is 1280(width)x1024(length) in size. The data is store in an 1d array called "CamBuff" with 1280*1024 in size.

```
Image is something like this:| 0   1   2...  1278   1279 |
                             |1280...               2559 |
                             |.    .    .      .         |
                             |.    .    .      . 1310719 |

CamBuff: [ 0  1  2.... 1279  1280 ... 1310719]
```

The image data should only contains 0 and 1, as it is a binary image data (Assume background = 0, object = 1).

There is a object in the image and I want to find the center position of it.

I have think of something like this (find the width of the object, but probably this is wrong):

```
int width = 1280;
int height = 1024;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c, startrow, startcol, endrow, endcol, objectwidth, objectheight;
int h = 1;
int widthstart = 0;
int colstart = 0;


    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<width; k++)      
            {                               
                a = CamBuff[k];         
                b = CamBuff[h];         
                c = b - a;

                if(c != 0 && widthstart == 0)   
                {                           
                    startrow = h;                                   
                    widthstart = 1;

                }
                if(c != 0 && widthstart == 1)
                {
                    endrow = k;
                    widthstart = 0;

                }
                h++;

                objectwidth = (endrow - startrow)*0.5;          

            }
        }
```

If there is a change (from background to object or vice versa), c != 0

How can I find the x and y center position of the object?

Comment: How do you define the center? The center of the minimum rectangle that the object is inscribed in, or the geometric (areal) center? The latter would take much more calculation.

Comment: OpenCV might help with this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the barycenter of a form. You must accumulate all positions of the pixels you want to keep, and divide by the count of these.

something like the following code will give you the solution.

Code not tested and don't compile, i've tried to take your notations replace Backgound by the value of backgound (0 in your case)

```
 const size_t acc_x=0, acc_y=0;
 for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<width; k++)      
        {   if( image[i*width+k] != Backgound )
            { 
                acc_x += k
                acc_y += i;
                ++counter
            }
        }
   }
  const size_t barycenter_x = acc_x / counter;
  const size_t barycenter_y = acc_y / counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an array for
 width and height. And then check each line for the middle of the object in it(middle of the object by the '1' in it) and put it in the array. and the same thing for the column.
After you created the 2 arrays you calculate the point by calculating the avarage of the width and height arrays. Good luck